# How to make a total count of messages / alerts indicator in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am not familiar with the exact term and keyword to search and Iam just begining to design. So I would like to ask if the term alert indicator is correct.

And how do I be able to do it on Twitter Bootstrap?

below is the image of the indicator i would like to accomplish.
Thanks..

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Take a look at Bootstrap's Badges: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#badges

Make a class that specifies a container for a glyphicon and badge and places the badge at a fixed offset from the icon. Something like this:

```
<div class="notification-icon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
    <span class="badge">19</span>
</div>
```

With CSS like this:

```
.notification-icon .glyphicon {
    ...
}

.notification-icon .badge {
    ...
}
```

You should easily be able to set it up so that the badge only shows when you have a nonzero number of notifications.

Comment: oh i see.. Thanks.. i complete forgot about that positioning it inside the div itself.. i got stuck on making it work on postioning it by padding or margin ...

Comment: I also wanted to fit the indicator icon (i used bell btw instead of envelope icon) within one bootstrap column so made following appends:
<a href="alerts.html">
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 notification-icon" title="Alarms">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span>
           <span class="badge" id="jt-alarm-count"> 9999 </span>
    </div>
</a>
Where using jquery, $("#jt-alarm-count") can be played around with.
Thanks Timothy

@ClannadSystem - isn't that an awesome anime (~‾▿‾)~